# Prove equivalence: $X$ compact $\Leftrightarrow \forall f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$, $f$ bounded $\Leftrightarrow \forall d, (X,d)$ bounded

Tags: general-topology

Given $(X, \tau)$, a metrizable topological space, and $d$, a metric on $X$ we say that $d$ is a "continuous metric" if $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Prove the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ compact
2. $\forall f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$, $f$ is bounded
3. $\forall d$ continuous, $(X,d)$ is bounded

I've been able to do $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ using Tychonof:

Since $(X, \tau)$ is compact then so is $X \times X$. Let $d$ be a continuous metric, then it is continuous on a compact space (i.e. $X\times X$) therefore $d(X,X) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is also compact. By Heine-Borel it follows that it is also bounded.

There's a hint for doing $(3) \Rightarrow (2)$ but I've exhausted all my options. I realized that if I can show somehow that $X$ is compact, then by continuity into $\mathbb{R}$ I would obtain the solution, but nothing seems to yield this. In any case, this doesn't follow the hint since it would be: $(3) \Rightarrow (1) \Rightarrow (2)$.

Realizing none of the theorems I'm familiar with that would enable me to state that $f(X)$ is compact are helpful, I tried playing around with the actual definitions of bounded and continuous to see how the "continuous $d$'s" fit in but there doesn't seem to be any apparent relation between them and the $f$'s.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you can use is to take a compatible metric $\rho$ on $X$ and define $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ by $d(x,y)=\rho(x,y)+|f(x)-f(y)|$.